# How to measure FPS of webcam in MatLab during recording while logging to disk?

Tags: matlab, logging, timestamp, disk, frame-rate

I'm working on a project for school, we have a nasty synchronization problem regarding framerate. We are using three webcameras, each of them seems to be recording with its own framerate, that changes dynamically during the measurement (change of lighting on the scene and so on). I Know how to record timestamps when logging mode is set to memory and how to compute fps from it, the problem is, that I can only do this before i start recording for real, because real videos are way too long and MatLab always runs out of memory before the recording is over. So I have to set logging mode to disk, you see. But when I do that, there seems to be no way to record timestamps. My point is to figure out how to record those timestamps during disk logging and then I would do a median of fps, which should pretty much fit the real fps of the recorded video (or most of the time at least). Thank you.

Comment: Ah nevermind guys, figured wayaround. For those reading this - it is possible to do it.

Comment: Set LoggingMode to disk&memory. Then set FramesAcquiredFcnCount of your vidObj to something sufficient for you. In my case, we have really slow pc and record from three cameras at once, so I found a value of 100 frames right about fine.

Then set your own FramesAcquiredFcn for the vidObj within the script. You do that by typing

set(vidObj,'FramesAcquiredFcn',@my_function);

Then write your function in the script somewhere. It always hase two input arguments that add up automatically - the source and event. So you define it like this:

Comment: function [fps]=my_function(src,evt)

I then do a getdata command, neglecting the bitmap information, curious only about timestamps.

[~,timestamps]=getdata(src,src.FramesAvailable);

This ensures, that it always wipes out all FramesAvailable, leaving nothing behind to consume memory. Then I process timestamps, count the difference, do a median, do the 1/median and oalla - I have fps. 

Hope this helps somebody.